# HTML file not working in Browser

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have created a simple - `HelloWorld.html` Webpage with HTML, JavaScript, CSS. 
When I run it from Eclipse IDE, It works perfectly on browser.

```
What it does is like: the page has 5 buttons, 
and hellow World is displayed from 5 different <div>'s  
that remains hidden and appears as inline after button click.
```

When I navigate to the work-space and try to open the `HelloWorld.html` file in browser manually, nothing comes correctly.

All  properties: positions and bgcolors etc declared in external css file has no effect on browser.

I know it sounds stupid, but I'm just hating myself for this. 
Does anyone know why is it behaving in this way?

PS: 
 1. I have no Server-side scripting in the file.
 2. HTML, JS, CSS are different file.

Comment: can you provide the complete code???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be that you are trying to use the css file with a realtive path, which changes when you don't host it temporarily as eclipse IDE does.

First, open the developer toolbar (f12) & check the network tab to see if the css file is being loaded at all.

Try using an absolute path instead & see if it changes anything.

Comment: this is the best answer considering that you did not paste any code

Comment: @loxxy~ Done. It works with absolute path. But I can't keep/use absolute path here. What I used earlier was: `<script src="../HelloWorld.js"></script>` & `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../index.css" />`. Is there any alternative for `../filename`?

Comment: @iKishore can't confirm, but I believe the HTML page will have access only to the sub directories & not the parent (which you are trying to reach with `..`).

Comment: @loxxy  Now I used `<script src="HelloWorld.js"></script>` & `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />`. Its perfectly working. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my Exp. i have seen this kind of problems many times, the Inbuilt browser of eclipse some times does not support all features especially when you doing like designing purpose.
you can use MS-IE 6 or Above version for same.
or you can try some other browsers like:- Mozilla,Chrome etc.
because it has features for developers for scripting , div , css and many more . so u can check with them.

Thanks,
Arvind

Comment: Tried with Safari, Chrome, IE9, Mozilla, Opera(all new versions). All failed. Thank you.

Comment: Posted this question after **checking my code properly**! Got my answer. Refresh page!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of file manager from which you have opened.
You just need to see the link in browser.
If it has a "content//:" in start then the css or JavaScript file you have linked in the HTML will not work.
What you need to do is change your file manager or create link manually.
To create a link manually you should use "file///:"in start for example if your file is in download then you should use something like that....
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/My%20Web/index.html
Or you can use ZArchiver file manager and go to your file and use open with option to open file in browser.